# Transaction is not active in the current thread

Tags: jpa, glassfish, jta

I keep getting the error message Transaction is not active in the current thread and i cannot think of a way to resolve this issue. This error keeps occurring on the page load before I press the button that should be issuing the method to insert data into my database.
Below i have entered my code:

```
    public String bookLesson(int lessonNo) throws Exception{
    try{
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        Lesson lesson = em.find(Lesson.class, lessonNo);
        booking.setLessonno(lesson);
        booking.setCustomername(customerName);
        booking.setCustomerphone(customerPhone);
        utx.begin();
        em.persist(booking);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e){
        utx.rollback();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return "lesson";
}
```

The method is being called from a webpage h:button so that once the user has input their name and phone number into textboxes which will be passed to the database hopefully. Also I am using a glassfish server if this information helps!
Here is also a copy of the stack trace returned on the error page

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction is not active in the current thread.
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.validateTransactionManager(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:447)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.rollbackDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:208)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.rollback(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:892)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.rollback(UserTransactionImpl.java:238)
at bean.bookingBean.bookLesson(bookingBean.java:146)
at bean.bookingBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.bookLesson(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutcomeTarget.getOutcome(UIOutcomeTarget.java:164)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getNavigationCase(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:136)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetButtonRenderer.encodeBegin(OutcomeTargetButtonRenderer.java:90)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:869)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:385)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:162)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: did you try to start transaction "utx.begin()" before calling set methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the transaction status before performing the rollback because it is which triggers your exception. 
You can use the `public int getStatus() throws SystemException;` method from the `TransactionManager` interface.
And you can compare the returned value with the `int` value associated to the `javax.transaction.Status` interface:

```
public final static int STATUS_ACTIVE= 0;
```

If the transaction is active, you perform a rollaback. Otherwise, you don't perform it.
You can do it :

```
catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
         // logger.error(e);  It is a better solution than logging in output.
        if (utx.getTransaction().getStatus()==Status.STATUS_ACTIVE){
           utx.rollback();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I tried moving the utx.begin() and still nothing. I then checked the status compared to that number and they're both the same. When i comment out the method, my webpage loads. I don't update the database from anywhere else on the website just this one location.

Comment: No problem :) When you catch the exception which is the status code of the tx ? I forgotten.  On which one of your instruction the exception is thrown ?

Comment: So the exception is thrown when the page loads. The user gets directed to this page from another and then needs to fill out a form. Nothing is getting displayed on the page just an error message pops up. Its also not letting me see the error message in the catch, sorry completely new to JSF.

Comment: No problem, you have to learn, it is normal  :)
In the stracktrace, you have : `at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.rollback(UserTransactionImpl.java:238)
at bean.bookingBean.bookLesson(bookingBean.java:146)`
So, your managed bean is called. Move  `utx.rollback();` as the last instruction of the catch as it is which trigger the exception and adds also this output before : `System.out.println(utx.getStatus());`

Comment: So i changed the bean and it gave (on the glassfish server console) a value that said info 6.

Comment: As expected, you have not current transaction. Normally, you should also have the original exception in the output. Can you show it ?

Comment: I believe this is the exception: Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'CUSTOMERNAME'  cannot accept a NULL value.
Error Code: 20000. It is saying it is a NULL value, but it is coming from a text box. On the page load the text box is null, how would i go about changing this?

Comment: I edited my answer for how to do the  rollback. For your JSF problem, it is simple : you should not call this method when the page is loaded but when you want to submit data with a commandButton for example. Besides, in bookLesson(), you should check data are valid before trying to persist them.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed this issue with my code!